# AFNetworking, JSON с файла

Tags: xcode, objective-c, iphone

Добрый день. Пользуюсь AFNetworking уже не первый раз, но всегда пользуюсь URL строкой. Сейчас же мне нужно использовать парсер, но вся информация лежит у меня в файлах, и я не могу заставить AFNetworking работать с ним. Подскажите как его заставить =(

P.S. Вот способ которым я тяню с нета...

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://httpbin.org/ip"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
//Присваеваем IP тексту или Lable 
} failure:nil];
[operation start];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, чтобы получить url для внутреннего файла:

```
    NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"name" withExtension:@"json"];
```

Если не сработает, убедись в том что у тебя файл находиться в твоем бандле

ПыСы зачем тебе AFNetworking для внутренних файлов? Все можно сделать проще

```
- (id)jsonRepresentationFromFileName:(NSString*)jsonFileName
{
    __autoreleasing NSError* error = nil;
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:jsonFileName ofType:@"json"];
    NSData *fileData = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:filePath];
    id values = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:fileData
                                                  options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    if (error != nil)
        @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:@"parsingError" reason:[error localizedDescription] userInfo:[error userInfo]];
    return values;
}
```

Comment: Я не успел написать свой ответ, Александр меня опредедил. 

Во-первых, AFJSONRequestOperation не дружит с локальными ресурсами.
Во-вторых, действительно, "зачем тебе AFNetworking для внутренних файлов"? @AlexanderSviridov привёл отличный пример того, как это сделать проще всего.

Comment: Дело в том, что мне дали файлы, в позже точ в точ будут только на API не хочетелось переделывать =(